# WaitForSingleObject doesn't wait the end of the process

Tags: c++, winapi, process, win32-process, waitforsingleobject

I would like to wait the end of the process execution (calc.exe) but it doesn't work.
My program finishes fast/now while my process(calc.exe) continue to run (I don't stopped it).

and WaitForSingleObject returns immediatly WAIT_OBJECT_0.

ps: I disabled my software anti-virus (AVIRA)

```
int main(int argc, char** arv)
{
STARTUPINFO si;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
si.cb = sizeof(si);
ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

const char * calcPrgm = "C:\\\\Windows\\System32\\calc.exe";
LPSTR calcPrgmLpstr = const_cast<LPSTR>(calcPrgm);

// Start the child process. 
if (!CreateProcess(NULL,   // No module name (use command line)
    calcPrgmLpstr,        // Command line
    NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
    NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
    FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
    0,              // No creation flags
    NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
    NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory 
    &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
    &pi)           // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
    )
{
    printf("CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError());
    return -1;
}

// Wait until child process exits.
auto ret = WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
printf("WaitForSingleObject ret = %x\n", ret);
if (ret == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
{
    printf("WaitForSingleObject ret ret == WAIT_OBJECT_0\n");
}
BOOL b = FALSE;
DWORD n = 0;
b = GetExitCodeProcess(pi.hProcess, &n);

// Close process and thread handles. 
CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
printf("WaitForSingleObject end\n");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: OK I see you lifted this from the MSDN https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/ProcThread/creating-processes so  is it failing to create the process? What does getlasterror return and what is `ret` WAIT_OBJECT_0?

Comment: this is of course work. `calc.exe` is exited. but before this it exec `Calculator.exe`

Comment: when `WaitForSingleObject` returns `WAIT_OBJECT_0` for `pi.hProcess` - process is really exit. you not take to account that you view another process

Comment: To wait on a chain of processes, use a [Job object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/procthread/job-objects). By default, when a parent process spawns a child process, the child process is added to the same Job that the parent process belongs to. So, create a Job, add the `calc.exe` process to it, and wait on the Job. The Job will be signaled when both `calc.exe` and `Calculator.exe` have exited. See [How do I wait until all processes in a job have exited?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130405-00/?p=4743)

Answer (score 1):

I found the error. "calc.exe" create another process before to exit. I created/called my own program with 1 line of code in the main "Sleep(60 * 1000);". It's ok now :)

Comment: It doesn't take a full minute for calc.exe to spawn a new instance of itself. Anyway, your "solution" is not a good one, it's a cop-out one. Remy gave you a good solution approach in the comments.